# oracle sql rank () over (partition by) function issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I got problem with rank() over (partition by) oracle function...

```
 insert into t_w_subs_x_po_hist_temp ( 
  SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
  VALID_FROM,
  VALID_TO,
  PO_ORDINAL_NO)
select ...      
 ... rank() over (partition by subscription_id order by valid_from) PO_ORDINAL_NO
```

But as a result in the target table, I got following output:

```
SUBSC ID   VALID_FROM        VALID_TO             PO_ORDINAL_NO
220144  21/08/2014 00:00:01 25/10/2016 12:02:42       1
220144  25/10/2016 12:02:43 25/07/2018 16:13:40       2
220144  25/07/2018 16:13:41 01/08/2022 09:41:12       3
220144  01/08/2022 09:41:13                           3
```

My question is why the value of PO_ORDINAL_NO for the last row in output did not get value of "4" inested of "3"?

Comment: If that is your real data and your real code, I can't think of any reason why you would get that output.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data; and a complete query. With the data you have presented the output is impossible so we cannot replicate your issue; you need to give us some way of replicating the errors so we can tell you why it happened.

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT valid_from, DUMP(valid_from), valid_to, DUMP(valid_to) FROM table_name WHERE subsc_id = 220144;`?

Comment: The output is what I attached above...rank function didn't work properly...I am trying to figure it out why